# Linux - Chrome memory calculations

Tags: linux, google-chrome, memory, memory-management, valgrind

I have used chrome with debug build on Linux for my experiment.

I ran chrome browser with debug build to run some web page, which is kind of loading lots of images.

To validate, i used "`cat /proc/render-pid/statm`" to check the memory.

To understand the allocation pattern, I have run with "`valgrind --tool=massif --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0`".

I see the RSS (2nd value in statm) increase from initial 133129 pages (before loading images) to 176562 pages(after loading images). And valgrind snapshot shows the memory allocated. (More than 140MB).  If you calculate from statm its around 165M (Excluding Shared memory)

Next I freed up every image ( cleared up the internal caches ). 
Now the Valgrind snapshot shows only 4MB of memory. 
statm RSS value reduce to 161916 pages.

(I agree that Valgrind might take memory. But I have similar behavior in case of running alone. )

What I couldnt get is :

- statm shows that total allocated in heap is around 165M, where as valgrind shows 140M
- After freeing, valgrind shows around 4M where as statm shows increase in memory of 27 from the start of value.

So how to find where the memory is allocated??

NOTE:

- valgrind doesnt show memory allocated via MMAP and SBRK (With the parameters which I passed) . But as per my understanding (With simple test program), the allocations via MMAP / SBRK will increase "Data" which 6th value in Statm output. 
  Hence I have ruled out that possibility.
- Also i have not used "tc-malloc".
- Since I am running chrome with valgrind, i see humongous amount of memory allocated. So generally I see only differences.
- I calculated the private memory using RSS Memory - Shared Memory (2nd - 3rd value in statm output)

The values from statm output:

- Initial Value : 370434 133129 9450 918 0 289639 0
- Peak Value:  412588 175355 10145 918 0 331197 0
- End Value (After freeing): 407473 161916 9573 918 0 326678 0